# speed up generate N unique random numbers code

Tags: php

I've been asked to generate all possible combinations in the range AA0000-ZZ9999(let's call it `folio`), for each combination I also need a 8 digits unique ramdom number (let's call it `attcode`), can't be consecutive, I know that there are a lot of combinations and the process will be slow, but as I'm using the `rand` function, and I've to validate that every `attcode` has to be unique, it is making my code slower, so if is it possible (I know it is, just don't know how), give me recommendations 'bout how can I improve this in my code

```
$alph = str_split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 1);
$code_cache = array();
foreach ($alph as $value1) {
  foreach ($alph as $value2) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        $n=$i;
        if($i<10){
            $n="000".$i;
        }
        elseif($i<100){
            $n="00".$i;
        }
        elseif($i<1000){
            $n="0".$i;
        }
        $code = rand(10000000, 99999999);
        while(in_array($code, $code_cache)){
            $code = rand(10000000, 99999999);
        }
        $code_cache[]=$code;
        echo $value1.$value2.$n.'-'.$code.'<br/>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The result you want is effectively every 2-"digit" base-26 number appended to every 4-digit base-10 number.  By definition, this requires the generation of `(26^2) * (10^4) = 6,760,000` combinations.  It's going to be slow...

Comment: know that already, but, if i permit `attcode` to be repeated, it runs way faster

Comment: i'm never able to generate all the combinations, to slow process, maybe i just need a better computer, lol.

Comment: Well, if I were you, I would make an algorithm that computes an attcode given the folio. This way, you don't have to store all the folios into the memory and prevent a time-out (which is bound to happen with 6.760.000 calculations). What is the application of this problem? Is it for research of some sort, where the applicants cannot guess the attcode belonging to the folio or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've totally cracked it this time. I'm actually a bit pleased with myself on this one:

```
// An array of 10000 0's
$attcodes1 = array_fill(0, 9999, 0);

// An array of 10000 from 0 - 9999
$attcodes2 = range(0, 9999);
// Not actually necessary but makes $attcodes appear more random
shuffle($attcodes2);

// Loop until the alphas roll over to 3 characters
for ($alpha = "AA", $num = 0; $alpha != 'AAA'; $num++) {
  if ($num == 1001) {
    $num = 0; // At 1000 reset the counter to 0
    $alpha++; // Roll over to next alpha sequence
  }
  $folio = sprintf("$alpha%04s", $num); // Generate folio

  // Here's the clever bit, if I do say so myself...
  // Loop while we are hitting 4 digit sequences that have used every other
  // possible 4 digit sequence and remove them from the options.
  // This is *very* unlikely to loop more than twice, if ever
  while ($attcodes1[$part1 = array_rand($attcodes1)] >= 9999) {
    array_splice($attcodes1, $part1, 1);
  }
  // Get a 4 digit sequence not used with $part1 before and make sure we never
  // get it again (increment counter)
  $part2 = $attcodes2[$attcodes1[$part1]++];
  // Now it just needs stitching together and left-padding with 0s
  $attcode = sprintf("%04s%04s", $part1, $part2);

  // Job done
  echo $folio.'-'.$attcode."\n";

}
```

...and all without the insane memory usage my early attempts were generating. Seriously, it takes **24 bytes** to store a 32 bit (*4 byte!*) integer in PHP.

Looking at the progress on my (pretty low spec) laptop, I'm estimating a 10 minute runtime from start to finish. This will decrease considerably if you don't echo the results on the fly. I think. Although I'm not sure what you'd do with them instead without burning up memory or getting stuck on disk I/O.

Comment: Thank you, nice code by the way, i didn't know about the `$alpha = "AA"` and `$alpha++`, neither the `sprintf("$alpha%04s", $num);`, lol, i need to read more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have made one function, please go through it

```
function fnGetRandomNumber($intLength = 6) 
{
  $arrAlphNumeric = array("c","d"); 
  $arrCharacters = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"); 
  $arrNumbers = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"); 
  $strNewNumber = ""; 
  $intCountNumberLength = 1; 
  do { 
     $strValue = $arrAlphNumeric[rand(0,1)]; 
     if($strValue == "c") { 
        $strNewNumber .= $arrCharacters[rand(0,25)]; 
      } else { 
        $strNewNumber .= $arrNumbers[rand(0,9)]; 
      } 
        $intCountPasswordLength++; 
    } while($intNumberLength >= $intCountNumberLength); 

    return $strNewNumber; 
}
```